# knockout.js computed function to create two arrays?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, computed-observable

I have an array of objects that a user can perform search on. I'm using a ko.computed function based on the search to create another array of matched items for display.

```
self.matchedRecords = ko.computed(function() {
  return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.transponders(), function(r) {
    return r.title.toLowerCase().indexOf($('.search-input').val().toLowerCase()) > -1
  }
};
```

This works great and I'm really impressed with the performance so far.

This issue is I also need the "unmatched" records because I have to perform an addition operation on them in some cases (60% of the time). I don't really want to create a second ko.computed function because then I have to run through this array a second time every time a search is performed.

So, my question: Is there a way that I can use the same ko.computed to create a second array of unmatched items? Basically run through the array and put each item in the matched or unmatched array...

If not, is it faster to:
1) create a second ko.computed to get the unmatched items from my array as the user searches; or
2) write an arrayDiff function and determine the unmatched items on demand if I need them.

Cheers!

Comment: just use a 2nd computed, you are falling into premature optimization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are worried about performance, you could have a non-observable array that you populate while you iterate the search results in your computed. Also note that you are repeatedly selecting using jQuery inside your loop, which I think negates any KO-caused slowdowns.

```
self.missedRecords = [];

self.matchedRecords = ko.computed(function() {
    var searchQuery = $('.search-input').val().toLowerCase(),
        transponders = self.transponders(),
        matched = [];

    // Clear out missed records
    self.missedRecords.length = 0;

    _.each(transponders, function(transponder) {
        if (transponder.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchQuery) >= 0) {
            matched.push(transponder);
        } else {
            self.missedRecords.push(transponder);
        }
    });

    return matched;
});
```

I used `_.each` from Underscore to keep the code shorter. The drawback of this approach is that changes to `missedRecords` can't (reliably) be bound to the UI (e.g. in case you have a `foreach` binding).

If you do need the `missedRecords` array to be observable, and still want to keep things fast(er), you could do something like this:

```
self.missedRecords = ko.observableArray([]);

self.matchedRecords = ko.computed(function() {
    var searchQuery = $('.search-input').val().toLowerCase(),
        transponders = self.transponders(),
        matched = [],
        missed = [];

    _.each(transponders, function(transponder) {
        if (transponder.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchQuery) >= 0) {
            matched.push(transponder);
        } else {
            missed.push(transponder);
        }
    });

    // Clear out missed records, without triggering subscriptions
    self.missedRecords().length = 0;

    // Copy the local missed array to the KO observable array
    // This will NOT trigger notifications
    ko.utils.arrayPushAll(self.missedRecords(), missed);

    // Tell KO that the observable array has mutated - this will trigger changes
    // to anything observing the missedRecords array
    self.missedRecords.valueHasMutated();

    return matched;
});
```

You could also skip `computed` altogether and just subscribe to changes to change the state of your arrays. For example:

```
self.missedRecords = ko.observableArray([]);
self.matchedRecords = ko.observableArray([]);

self.transponders.subscribe(function(newTransponders) {
    var matched = [],
        missed = [];

    _.each(newTransponders, function(transponder) {
        // Populate matched/missed local arrays
    });

    // Copy the arrays to the observableArray instances using the technique above
});
```

Comment: I think you have it with the subscribe.. never even thought of doing it that way - thanks!